# How to setup samba server on Centos (Amazon Ami 2 )?

Tags: centos

I am trying to setup Fsx on aws for windows, but it is costly, so i need help to setup samba server on centos/Amazon Linux 2, And map it as windows network drive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Open port 445 (SMB port) to allow access.

```
sudo yum install samba   
sudo service smb restart 
sudo adduser test 
sudo smbpasswd -a test 
echo "[global] 
        disable spoolss = Yes 
        dns proxy = No 
        load printers = No 
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m 
        map to guest = Bad User 
        max log size = 1000 
        obey pam restrictions = Yes 
        pam password change = Yes 
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d 
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:                                                                                                             * %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* . 
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u 
        printcap name = /dev/null 
        security = USER 
        server string = %h server 
        syslog = 0 
        unix password sync = Yes 
        idmap config * : backend = tdb 
[test] 
        comment = test Share 
        create mask = 0664 
        directory mask = 0775 
        max connections = 8 
        path = /home/test 
        read only = No 
        valid users = test 
" >> /etc/samba/smb.conf 
 
sudo service smb restart
```

To map this to windows server

1. Use your centos local ip with (ip addr)
2. In windows open This pc and click on computer on top left corner
3. Click on map network drive
4. add \\localip\[name of profile] in this case \\localip\test
5. Check connect using different credentials
6. Use the credentials created during setup